# How to create three buttons in UINavigationbar in iPhone programmatically?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm developing a small application. I need to create three buttons in a subclass. One button is `add`, another one is `search` and the last one is `back`. I also create left and right buttons. But I can't create search button in the center of the navigation bar. How can I create it? My code is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
[super viewDidLoad];
UIBarButtonItem *flipButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Flip"                                            
                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                               target:self 
                               action:@selector(flipView)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = flipButton;
[flipButton release];

UIBarButtonItem *flipButtons = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                               initWithTitle:@"Add"                 
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                               target:self 
                               action:@selector(addbuttonview)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = flipButtons;
[flipButtons release];

}
```

How to create a middle button in the navigation bar? Please help me.

Comment: I suggest you to use `UISegmentedControl `

Comment: ok use this. but how to use in navigation bar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is the code to use segment control in navigation bar programatically

```
NSArray* arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Log_Button.png"], [UIImage   imageNamed:@"Chart_Button.png"], nil];
segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:arr];
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(action)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[segmentedControl setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
[arr release];
UIBarButtonItem *rb = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:rb];
[rb release];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
UIButton *btnBack = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        btnBack.frame = CGRectMake(10, 4, 100, 50);
        [btnBack setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"button_back" ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
        [btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(btnBackPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:btnBack];

UIButton *btnHome = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        btnHome.frame = CGRectMake(115, 4, 38, 30);
        [btnHome setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"header_icon_home" ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnHome addTarget:self action:@selector(btnHomePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:btnHome];



UIButton *searchBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        searchBtn.frame=CGRectMake(175, 2, 60, 40);
        [searchBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(seachbtnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [searchBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Search.jpg"] forState:0];
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:searchBtn];
```

take three UIButtons and Add to navigationBar.set Frames Images As Per Ur Design.

Comment: Error contain this line "BUTTON_BACK_TAG" is undeclared. How to solve  this.

Comment: Those Are Prag marks. so here we have 2 solutions 1)giveing different tags for same selector 2) writing different selectors